# TKInter iniciando janela antes do restante da programação. (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, venho pedir a ajuda de alguém mais experiente que eu nesse assunto. Estou tentando utilizar o TKinter e o PyAutoGui para automatizar uma tarefa maçante do meu cotidiano. Meu objetivo é criar um looping, ele precisa executar sem a janela do Tkinter no primeiro loop, da segunda em diante, abrir a janela, pois o botão que coloquei tem que "despausar" ao looping e continuar repetindo até que eu pare a programação.
Já tentei utilizar até o for in range, mas sem sucesso..

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time
from time import sleep

def sd():
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.click(69, 90, duration= 1)
    time.sleep(4.5)
    pyautogui.click(116, 86, duration= 1)
    time.sleep(12)
    pyautogui.click(394, 88, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(101, 575, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(153, 419, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(213, 578, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(714, 571, duration= 1)

janela = Tk()
bt = Button(janela, width=20, text="Próximo CTE", command=sd)
bt.place(x=50, y=50)
janela.geometry("250x100+200+200")
janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que execute o looping antes de abrir a janela do `tkinter`, basta chamar a função `sd()` antes da linha 18 > `janela = Tk()`:

```
sd()  # Chama a função sd
janela = Tk()
bt = Button(janela, width=20, text="Próximo CTE", command=sd)
```

Para fazer com que a função fique em looping até que algum comando o pare, importe a biblioteca **keyboard** com `pip install keyboard`, em seguida crie a função `loop()` que irá executar a função `sd()` até que você mantenha a tecla `ESC` pressionada:

```py
def loop():
    while True:
        sd()
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ESC'):
            break
```

Altere o método `command` do botão de **sd** para **loop**:

```
bt = Button(janela, width=20, text="Próximo CTE", command=**loop**)
```

Clique no botão da tela do `tkinter` para que inicie o looping novamente.

---

### Resultado:

```py
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time
from time import sleep
import keyboard


def sd():
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.click(69, 90, duration= 1)
    time.sleep(4.5)
    pyautogui.click(116, 86, duration= 1)
    time.sleep(12)
    pyautogui.click(394, 88, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(101, 575, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(153, 419, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(213, 578, duration= 1)
    pyautogui.click(714, 571, duration= 1)

def loop():
   """Chama a função sd() em looping ate que a tecla 'ESC' se mantenha pressionada"""
    while True:
        sd()
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ESC'):
            break
    

sd()  # Chama a função sd
janela = Tk()
bt = Button(janela, width=20, text="Próximo CTE", command=loop)
bt.place(x=50, y=50)
janela.geometry("250x100+200+200")
janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. funcionou perfeitamente !